# Ошибка у кода из книги

Tags: python

Совсем недавно я начал учить python по книге, и там сказали написать и запустить код. Написать я написал, а вот сама игра не запускается, и где ошибка понять не могу. Книга называется "Учим python, делая крутые игры" автор Эл Свейгарт, игра "Охотник за сокровищами". Может кто-то уже с этим сталкивался, и сможет пояснить?

Пишет, что ошибка где-то здесь:

```
for row in range(15):
    if row < 10:
      extraSrace = ' '
    else:
      extraSrace = ''

    boardRow = ''
    for column in range(60):
      boardRow += board[column][row]
      print('%s%s %s %s' % (extraSrace, row, boardRow, row))

  print()
  print(' ' + ('0123456789' * 6))
  print(tensDigitsLine)
```

И тут:

```
while True:
    sonarDevice = 20
    theBoard = getNewBoard()
    theChests = getRandomChests(3)
    drawBoard(theBoard)
    previousMoves = []

    while sonarDevice > 0:
      print('Осталось гидролокаторов: %s. Осталось сундуков: %s.' % (sonarDevice, len(theChests)))

      x, y = enterPlayerMove(previousMoves)
      previousMoves.append([x, y])

      moveResult = makeMove(theBoard, theChests, x, y)
    if moveResult == False:
        continue
    else:
        if moveResult == 'Вы нашли сундук с сокровищами на затонувшем судне!':
          for x, y in previousMoves:
            makeMove(theBoard, theChests, x, y)
        drawBoard(theBoard)
        print(moveResult)

    if len(theChests) == 0:
      print('Вы нашли все сундуки с сокровищами на затонувших судах! Поздравляем!')
      break
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\volodia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\sonar2.py", line 151, in <module>
    drawBoard(theBoard)
  File "C:\Users\volodia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\sonar2.py", line 33, in drawBoard
    boardRow += board[column][row]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: а тексты ошибок где? вот поставьте себя на место человека, который захотел вам помочь? как он по куску программы должен определить, что у вас не так?

Comment: текст ошибки внизу:) я тоже не сразу нашел. Но там очевидно, в массиве board просто нет 60 столбцов. А вот почему - это уже другой вопрос

Comment: @strawdog, текст ошибки есть внизу. просто отформатировано плохо

Comment: я ещё доформатировал:)

Comment: Если это [вот эта игра](https://inventwithpython.com/sonar.py), то код оттуда вроде рабочий. Может переводчик книги чего накосячил, сверяйте.

Comment: @GrAnd действительно переводчики намудрили. спасибо!

Comment: уточните где была опечатка. вдруг ктото столкнётся с такойже прлблемой